# Insert additional column to outlined group in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2010

I'm very newby in Excel and here is the issue I faced today: I have list of data where some of the values in column A are repeated a few times, and I have a list of pairs A' values - A' attributes.
Here is my list:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
Dan          green      342
Tess         blue       242
Sasha        yellow      11
Dan          red        123
Sasha        purple     251
```

And my pairs:

```
Column 1    Column 2
Dan         21
Tess        19
Sasha       17
```

Is it possible somehow (and quite easily) in Excel to get the respective value from Column1-Column2 and put it to Column D? So it will look like:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D
Dan          green      342         21
Tess         blue       242         19
Sasha        yellow      11         17
Dan          red        123         21
Sasha        purple     251         17
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Column A starts at A1 and the pairs data in A10:B12. Try a VLOOKUP function in column D1 VLOOKUP(A1,$A$10:$B$12,2,0) and drag the formula down. Cell A1 would be Dan, the range would be your pairs data (i have assumed they are in Cells A10:B12, they may be somewhere else) and the 2 is the second column of the pairs data (the result you wish to be shown in column D).

Make sure you fix/hold the range (i.e. put dollar signs in between letters as shown above).